# load tableview inside uitableviewcell swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Hi i'm trying to add `UITableview` inside a `UITableViewCell`. I had connected the outer tableview cell to the view controller and the inner tableview(inside the cell) to the custom cell class and do the following code

```
//cellforrow of the outer tableview:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HistoryCell")! as! OrderHistoryTableViewCell
    print(ordersArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("items"))
    cell.lbl_orderStatus.text = ordersArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("status") as? String
    cell.lbl_time.text = ordersArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("timestamp") as? String
    let vc = OrderHistoryTableViewCell() // Custom cell class
    vc.tableview_reload(ordersArray[indexPath.row]as! NSMutableDictionary) //pass value to the tableview inside the cell
    return cell
}

//code in the custom cell class

func tableview_reload(dict : NSMutableDictionary){
    orderItemsarray.removeAllObjects()
    let itemsDict = dict.valueForKey("items") as! NSMutableDictionary
    for (_,value) in itemsDict
    {
        let tempDict = value as! NSMutableDictionary
        orderItemsarray.addObject(tempDict)
    }
    self.tbl_Items.reloadData() // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.orderItemsarray.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell : UITableViewCell!
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell");
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    return cell
}
```

The data is passed and the func tableview_reload in the custom cell class is called. But when i try to reload the tableview in the custom cell class fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a optional value occurs.

I had checked the outlet connection and it is connected to the custom cell class. Please advice

Comment: try print the `tbl_Items` before called reload

Comment: Check outlet `tbl_Items` is properly connected.

Comment: @Tj3n po tel_Items gives this
(lldb) po tbl_Items
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: @NiravD  
The outlets of tbl_Items are connected to OrderHistoryTableViewCell which is the custom cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new instance using `OrderHistoryTableViewCell()` you need to use reused cell that you have created using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, so remove line `let vc = OrderHistoryTableViewCell()` and call `tableview_reload` method on `cell`.

```
cell.tableview_reload(ordersArray[indexPath.row]as! NSMutableDictionary)
return cell
```

Comment: This is correct...i dont even understand why he already dequeue but still create new instance of the cell....speechless

Comment: @Mohanraj Welcome mate :)